# How to convert a map to a new map and handle possible duplicated new key in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, aggregate-functions

I would like to convert a map to a new map, the new key of the new map will be generated by the old key, but the new key could be duplicated, so I need to aggregate results for the same new key.

for example: `val oldMap = Map(2 -> 111, 3 -> 222, 4 -> 333)`

the new key will be generated by some function, e.g. **k => k % 2**. Therefore, the new key will be, **0** and **1**. And for the same new key, I want to sum up the result (or pass some aggregation function)

Result new map: `Map(0 -> 444, 1 -> 222)`

I tried `oldMap.groupBy( k => k._1 % 2)` but the result is `Map(0 -> Map(2 -> 111, 4 -> 333), 1 -> Map(3 -> 222))`, the value is part of the old map. And I don't know how to pass an aggregate function.

Comment: If you have **cats** in scope, you may use `foldMap`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I guess, `Map`/`Iterable` is not `Foldable`. Ah, maybe you meant with `.toList`/`.toMap`

Comment: @DmytroMitin you may do it with a `toList` before, or you may use the unordered version of `foldMap`

Answer (score 3):

[groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Map.html#groupMapReduce%5BK,B%5D(key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,B%5D) is pretty handy for this situation if you have Scala 2.13 or later:

```scala
oldMap.groupMapReduce(_._1 % 2)(_._2)(_ + _)
```

The first argument is the same as `groupBy`. The second argument says just keep the value, and the third argument sums all the values in each group.

Answer (score 2):

```
val oldMap = Map(2 -> 111, 3 -> 222, 4 -> 333)
val newMap = oldMap.groupBy { case (k, v) => k % 2 } 
                  .view
                  .mapValues(_.values.sum) 
                  .toMap // if we need convert to strict Map.
```

You can use the 'groupBy' mehod to group the entries and then use 'mapValues' for aggrigation. You can replace the '_.values.sum' function with any other aggregation function.

Edit: As mentioned by @Dmytro Mitin, we can use view to create a lazy view of the original map, and then use mapValues
Use of .view enables us to use mapValues without converting it to collection. Once all these aggregation operations are done, we can use toMap and get the map back

Comment: `.mapValues` on `Map` is deprecated since 2.13.0. So maybe `val newMap = oldMap.groupBy { case (k, _) => k % 2 }.view.mapValues(_.values.sum).toMap`

Answer (score 1):

*(Based on @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez's comment)*

You can use Cats as well

```
import cats.syntax.foldable._

oldMap.groupBy(_._1 % 2).view.mapValues(_.toList.foldMap(_._2)).toMap
```

or

```
import cats.Foldable
import cats.syntax.foldable._
import alleycats.std.map._

oldMap.groupBy(_._1 % 2).view.mapValues(Foldable[Map[Int, *]].fold(_)).toMap
```

Comment: Nah I meant something simpler: `oldMap.unorderedFoldMap { case (k, v) => Map(f(k) -> v) }`